# Should Remote notificatgion on iOS trigger push notifications post UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification?

Tags: ios

As if I understand the documentation properly if a Push notification Pop up appears I UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification should be posted. But it won't.

I have added:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(pauseGame)
                                                name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

to

```
applicationDidFinishLaunching
```

Answer (score 0):

UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification is posted when the app is no longer active and loses focus.

If you want to listen from Remote Notifications you should implement in AppDelegate the following method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
```

And to manage remote notifications when the app is not running you should manage the launchOptions from

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

Comment: I have done that. Now the problem is that when the popup window with the notification appears I need to pause the game.

Comment: Sorry @Zingam but this is a different question and I need more information to help you with that problem.